# Partial Trait Implementation in Case Class Companion Object

Tags: scala

I have a trait that describes two methods: one "static" and one not. I would like a case class to extend the trait like so

```
trait SomeTrait {
  def nonStaticMethod(): Int
  def staticMethod(): String
}

case class SomeTraitImplementor(a: Int) extends SomeTrait {
  def nonStaticMethod(): Int = {
    a + 1
  }
}

object SomeTraitImplementor {
  def staticMethod(): String = "static response"
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Not really, the best you can do is have two traits and document your users. But even still, the usage of such a trait is mostly impossible unless you also define some way to get the companion object. - In general, this kind of design is better expressed using a typeclass instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put implementation into the trait itself as the default:

```
trait SomeTrait {
  def nonStaticMethod(): Int
  def staticMethod(): String = SomeTraitImplementor.staticMethod()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is you can't do something like that. Sounds like you are trying to apply a Java style in Scala. Scala has [Singleton Objects](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/singleton-objects.html) which are just a singleton class. You can have a Singleton without having a class. Having a Singleton object with the same name as a class is known as [Companion Object](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/domain-modeling-tools.html#companion-objects) which is the closes thing to static methods in Java.

You don't need to define a class and then static methods inside like this

```
class Calculator {
  public static int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
  }
}
```

You can directly define objects like you did and don't even define a class with the same name. So, you can't define inside a [trait](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/traits.html) what is an instance method and what is a class method. Based on an `singleton object` in scala is just a class like any other class except that it whill only has one instance, it can inherit attributes and methods from another class or trait. So, what is only defined in the trait, it will need to be implemented in the child `class` or `singleton object` except in an `abstract class` or another `trait`.

In the piece of code you provided, the solution could be to split the trait in two traits and make the class extend one trait and the singleton object extend the other one. If you want to prevent a trait being extended by another class or trait, you can consider using inner classes with modifier accesors.

Maybe if you share what you are trying to solve at domain level, another approach could be suggested.